# How to partition Fs2 Stream by key to transform each partition separately?

Tags: scala, fs2

What I want to achieve, **for example**, given data:

```
time, part, data
0, a, 3
1, a, 4
2, b, 10
3, b, 20
3, a, 5
```

and transformation:

```
stream.keyBy(_.part).scan(0)((s, d) => s + d)
```

get:

```
0, a, 3
1, a, 7
2, b, 10
3, b, 30
3, a, 12
```

---

I've tried partition it using `groupAdjacentBy`, but it is becomes too complex, because I need to preserve complex state between each Chunk with Key. 
I wonder if there something similar to Flink DataStream.[keyBy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/)? Or simpler way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found interesting [solution](https://gist.github.com/kiambogo/8247a7bbf79f00414d1489b7e6fc90d0) (cannot be `flatten`, though)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as stated, can be solved by "partitioning" in the scan operation itself:

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2._

case class Element(time: Long, part: Symbol, value: Int)

val elements = Stream(
  Element(0, 'a, 3),
  Element(1, 'a, 4),
  Element(2, 'b, 10),
  Element(3, 'b, 20),
  Element(3, 'a, 5)
)

val runningSumsByPart = elements
  .scan(Map.empty[Symbol, Int] -> none[Element]) {
    case ((sums, _), el@Element(_, part, value)) =>
      val sum = sums.getOrElse(part, 0) + value
      (sums + (part -> sum), el.copy(value = sum).some)
  }
  .collect { case (_, Some(el)) => el }

runningSumsByPart.covary[IO].evalTap(el => IO { println(el) }).compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
```

Outputs:

> Element(0,'a,3)
>
> Element(1,'a,7)
>
> Element(2,'b,10)
>
> Element(3,'b,30)
>
> Element(3,'a,12)

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this. First split, then merge. I don't know yet how to return 2 streams though. I just know how to process them in one place and then merge them together.

```scala
    val notEqualS = in
      .filter(_.isInstanceOf[NotEqual])
      .map(_.asInstanceOf[NotEqual])
      ...

    val invalidS = in
      .filter(_.isInstanceOf[Invalid])
      .map(_.asInstanceOf[Invalid])
      ...

    notEqualS.merge(invalidS)
```